# Efficient way to read large binary data in an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, large-data

I'm attempting to write a web page that loads an upwards of a gigabyte of binary data.  The page is ran directly off the local disk, not from a web server.

I tried encoding the data as base64 and embedded it through a script file, but the browser slowed to a crawl and eventually crashed from out-of-memory errors.  I then tried encoding the data as an Uint8Array, but it ran into the same problem.  I've also tried breaking the binary data down into multiple files and retried both methods on them, but it reached the point where I had over 100 script files and the browser still ran into out-of-memory errors.

So far, the only way to load the data into memory is to use the File API.  However, it's not intuitive to have to select these files every time in order to use the web page.

Are there any other methods for reading large binary data into a web page without having to use the File API?  I can't use AJAX/fetch because this is ran directly off the local disk.

Comment: what kind of file are you trying to embed?

Comment: *"I can't use AJAX/fetch because this is ran directly off the local disk."* So...don't do that. :-) It's trivial to install a local web server process, and use that instead. Or alternately, you could use Electron or one of the other environments that lets you build local apps with web technologies.

Comment: The reason for not using a web server or Electron is because of the business requirements.  Our customers are in extremely locked down environments and they cannot just run arbitrary executables.  Think government levels of lock-down.  The kind of files I'm embedding is for a local search index that will be executed with Javascript.